# download and save image to root

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

How would i download and save an image to the root of the application so basically i can access the image via

```
[UIImage imageNamed:@"myimage.jpg"];
```

Thanks

Mason

Comment: imageNamed: works only with images you deployed with your app-package. But you can't write to this package - you have to save your image to your app documents folder.

Comment: Ohh ok so how would i do this via the documents folder ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to get the Image Data

```
NSData *imageData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://media03.linkedin.com/mpr/mpr/shrink_80_80/p/3/000/064/2e2/1bd3849.jpg"]];
```

Then you need to write the data to Documents directory

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0]; 
NSString *pathLD = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"imageLD%d.jpeg",[[NSDate date] timeIntervalSince1970]]]; 

NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if (![fileManager fileExistsAtPath: pathLD]){
    [imageData writeToFile:pathLD atomically:YES];
} else {
    NSLog(@"File exists at path:%@", pathLD);
}
```

To get the image from Documents you do:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:pathLD];
```

Good luck :D;

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't for various reasons. Consider your application directory as being read-only.

You should use the Documents or Library directory. Apple recommends that you should use the Documents directory if your files should be user-accessible via iTunes (if you have enabled the file sharing via iTunes), or use a custom subdirectory of Library (which you need to create with NSFileManager) if it shouldn't be user-visible (but should be backed up).

You can query the path to the Library directory like this:

```
NSArray *paths;
paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSLibraryDirectory,
            NSUserDomainMask, YES);
// dir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
```

Substitute `NSLibraryDirectory` with `NSDocumentsDirectory` to get the Documents directory.

Then you would make a method that returns the full path to your image, and you would then do:

```
[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[self pathForImage:@"myimage.jpg"]]
```

Comment: So how would i save the image in the first place ?